# Why espresso test is needed in Android?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, recorder

Why automated UI testing using espresso framework important whereas manual testing is much more comfortable and time-saving. Because it doesn't need to write any test cases in code. Please kindly give some industry-level benefits of it.

Comment: Please ask a specific programming questions! Visit espresso's website to get more information about it, ask Google ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing UI testing in Android Studio.

To start the Espresso Test Recorder select *Run -> Record Espresso Test*.

There is a [short video here](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder.html). It will put the java code it creates in your folder.

To run all the UI tests right click your folder and choose *Run Tests in 'app/src/androidTest/javafolder'*.

The results of the tests should be displayed in the Run tab.